# Display an image contained in a byte[] with ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, strong-typing

I've a view with a strong type. This strong type has a field consisting of a byte[], this array contains a picture.

Is it possible to display this image with something like @Html.Image(Model.myImage) ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a controller action method that returns an image as a FileContentResult:

```
public FileContentResult Display(string id) {
   byte[] byteArray = GetImageFromDB(id);
   return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Then you can create an ActionLink to the action method in the view using the image id from the model.

Comment: It's exactly this I needed, but I used a new File(...) not a FileContentResult

Comment: @J4N, what do you mean by "use a new File(...)"?

Comment: You can use the "File(...)" controller method but there is no "new"

Comment: Note: for an image of any size, you would want to do this using a streaming API, deferring the iteration (via a moderate buffer) to the ActionResult.

Comment: @DmitryStarosta
Would we strongly type the View to a "FileContentResult" object then?

Comment: The "ViewResult" object is the only one that requires a Razor/ASPX view. Other action result objects like the "FileContentResult" or "JsonResult" do not need a view.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how big the image is. If it is small, you could write something to base-64 encode it and embed it in the html, [like any of these](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=base%2064%20inline%20image%20html).

For a [concrete example from here](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html):

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPbWLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVrApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KTkpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxMAF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=" alt="British Blog Directory" width="80" height="15">
```

If the image is of any appreciable size, you may want instead to write a route that allows lookup via some key to the image, i.e. a route like `/images/{id}` - in that route you fetch the image binary and use [`return File(bytes, contentType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208.aspx), additionally setting caching headers (and remember to re-check any necessary security). In your html you would just have an

```
<img src="/images/@imageId" ... />
```

(using razor syntax, but similar for aspx).

The separate route approach requires an additional hop to the server, but allows caching at the client (the inline base-64 approach puts the data on every request).

Comment: There is a good implementation of this contained in the code for ASP.Net Sprite and Image Optimization Framework (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was wonderful for me, because I had on-the-fly made image and I wanted to show it in ajax way. After some hours at last your suggestion solved my problem!

Comment: About the Route approach we can read here http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-3-Controller-for-Serving-Images.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you already happen to have the image loaded in your model as a `byte[]` array you can do this as @Marc Gravell mentions in [his answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041056/114029)

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo)" />
```

This greatly simplifies the whole process and you won't need to have a specific `FileContentResult` action method and hit the database again (see @Dmitry S's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048548/114029)) just to fetch that `byte[]` array with your image/photo since you already have it loaded in your model.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you'd need a new action that gets the byte array (from a database?) and returns the image via the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) method....

Then generate an anchor that points to that action, that way the image can be loaded while the page is loading, speeding up the display.

Answer (score 1):

Look at WebImage class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.99).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would design a simple generic handler for serving your images. This handler could, given some parameter, load images from the database, and write them to the http output stream.

```
public class UserImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        // Get the stream from the database
        var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in loading and saving the image.  You should just send the original stream.