# Controller returned data not binding to image in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get image from database and display it in the view. image is retrieved but from database but not binding to image. This is my controller code

```
public ActionResult GetSignatureDetails()
        {

     byte[] image = (from m in objIycEntity.Signatures
                                 where m.SignatureID == 5
                                 select m.Signature1).FirstOrDefault();
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());
                    return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpeg");
             }
```

And this is my view

```
  <img src='@Url.Action("GetSignatureDetails","Agent")' />
```

But always image src in firebug is src="/Agent/GetSignatureDetails"

Please can any one help me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040920/display-an-image-contained-in-a-byte-with-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: Did you try change your return content to "    return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");" ?

Comment: What do you mean "not binding"? Does the browser's tools show you the image is being downloaded? What other messages does the browser show you?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried it this way?

```
    public FileContentResult GetSignatureDetails()
    {
        byte[] image = (from m in objIycEntity.Signatures
                        where m.SignatureID == 5
                        select m.Signature1).FirstOrDefault();
        return File(image, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Comment: Answering a question consists of understanding the problem, researching a solution and then posting an answer. You skipped the first two steps and you encourage cargo cult programming (you copied the useless `new MemeoryStream()` code, and what does `return new File()` do different from `return new FileContentResult()`, why would that solve the issue, does it even compile?). Post a comment instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster too much code to comment. But you right, there should not be `new`. I suppose promlem is not in `FileContentResult` part, but in `ActionResult` part.

Comment: The comment would be _"Have you tried `return File(...)` instead of `return new FileContentResult(...)`?"_, which would easily fit in a comment (as demonstrated here). I'm still not sure what you think this will fix, [what do you think `Controller.File()` does internally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Comment: @CodeCaster same thing, that `new FileContentResult` i suppose. It's just cleaner.

Comment: Cleaner perhaps, but it doesn't do anything different, hence it wouldn't solve OP's problem, which was my point.

Comment: @CodeCaster why you think so? what about `FileContentResult` or even `FileStreamResult` instead of `ActionResult`, i suppose that's the main problem.

Comment: If that were the issue, OP would have a compile-time error, not an (improperly described) issue at runtime. [All mentioned `...Result` classes inherit from `ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I give you a sample code hope this will help you:

View :

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.AgentProfile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "imageDemo";
}

<h2>imageDemo</h2>


<img width="100" height="80" src="/Profile/ShowImage/2" alt=""  />
```

And Controller Code Like this:

```
 public ActionResult ShowImage(int id)
        {
            if (id>0)
            {
                AgentProfile objag = new AgentProfile();
                MvcApplication2.Models.Image obj = new MvcApplication2.Models.Image();
                obj.ImageID = id;
                DataSet ds = obj.SelectImage();
                objag.ImageSource = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageContent"];
                //objag.ImageSource = (byte[])row["ImageContent"];
                return File(objag.ImageSource, "image/jpg");
            }

            else
            {
             return   RedirectToAction("Index");
            }  
        }
```

Thanks.